# How to implement event hierarchy not based in HTML5 elements

Tags: html, typescript, dom

I want to write a component set out of HTML elements. For example:

```js
export default class Control implements EventTarget {
    // parent control, not HTML "parentElement"
    parent: Control | null;
    private _events: Map<string, EventListener[]> = new Map;

    // addEventListener(...) {}
    // removeEventListener(...) {}
    // dispatchEvent(...) {}
}
```

Subtype:

```js
export default class TabBar extends Control {
    // ...
}
```

So I'd implement `EventTarget` and any events would be subtype of the standard DOM's `Event` type. However, I want to support proper event propagation, both capture and bubbling phases.

The problem is, if I implement the standard DOM's `EventTarget` type, I must also use the standard DOM's `Event` type. It's a problem because I'm unable to set the value of `event.target`, `event.currentTarget` and `event.eventPhase`: see the constructor at [www.developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event).

One solution is for me to reinvent `Event`, and consequently reinvent `EventTarget`, but this would lead to duplicate code and lead to ambiguity. Is there anything I missing?

Another solution is to mix HTML and my component set, where my set will use simple event listening properties, like `onchange: ((d: EventData) => void) | null`.

Comment: Out of curiosity ... what is the support of event propagation outside of DOM good for? And coming up with own implementations of `EventTarget` and `Event` for/within an own type system which is not connected to the DOM, is a totally valid approach.

Comment: There is no `implements` in Javascript.

Comment: @PeterSeliger To be honest I'm not sure I need this, but it might be useful if my code base gets larger.

Answer (score 0):

It seems not possible to mutate properties like `target`, `eventPhase` and so on, which led me to create a small package for constructing your own event listeners where these properties are mutable. Also, you can use TypeScript generics to allow mapping event type (for example, `'mouseover'`) to event data type (`MouseEvent`):

```js
import { EventTarget, EventRegistry, Event, } from 'byo-event-system';

interface EventHandlersEventMap {
    "someevent": RegExp; // listener takes a RegExp
    "anotherevent": boolean; // listener takes a Boolean
}

export class MyType implements EventTarget {
    private _eventRegistry = new EventRegistry;

    addEventListener<E extends keyof EventHandlersEventMap>(type: E, listener: (evt: EventHandlersEventMap[E]) => void, useCapture: boolean = false): void {
        this._eventRegistry.addEventListener(type, listener as ((evt: Event): void), useCapture);
    }

    removeEventListener<E extends keyof EventHandlersEventMap>(type: E, listener: (evt: EventHandlersEventMap[E]) => void): void {
        this._eventRegistry.removeEventListener(type, listener as ((evt: Event): void));
    }

    dispatchEvent(event: Event): boolean {
        return this._eventRegistry.dispatchEvent(event);
    }

    hasEventListener(type: string): boolean {
        return this._eventRegistry.hasEventListener(type);
    }
}
```

You can find it on [www.npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/package/byo-event-system).